# Get list of inventory items from NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to retrieve an array or list of specific inventory items in NetSuite with one call? I can not seem to find any documentation regarding this. I have gone through the SuiteTalk training course and it does not contain any information on retrieving a list of items without the internalID.

On page 73 of [this document](https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1482&c=1002555&h=ce3e9305c0c399383681&_xt=.pdf) there is a function `getInventoryItemList(itemKeysArray)` that is called with an array of inventory item id's. However this function does not exist anywhere and I am assuming is a custom function but they never show the code for it.

The only two ways I can see doing this would be to pull every single inventory item out of NetSuite and import the internalID's into our local database, this seems like a lot of extra work to me. Another option I thought of is to loop over an array of the line items and perform an ItemSearchBasic for every element and get the internalID that way, this seems like a worse idea than just storing them in the local database. I am hoping someone can confirm and show me if there is a much easier way of doing what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of what I use when I need to get the a list of items (minus company specific data).  I just removed our data, and set it build/return an array.  This is in SuiteScript 2.0, just FYI.

```
require(['N/search','N/record'],function(search,record){
  function buildItemArray(){
    var itemArray=[];
    searchItems();
    itemArray=runSearch(itemArray);
    deleteSearch();
    log.debug(itemArray);
  }

  function searchItems(context){
    var itemSearch=search.create({
      type:search.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
      title:'Inventory_Item_Search',
      id:'customsearch_inventory_item_search',
      columns:['internalid','itemid'],
      filters:['isinactive','is','F']
    });
    itemSearch.save();
  }

  function runSearch(itemArray){
    var mySearch=search.load({id:'customsearch_inventory_item_search'});
    mySearch.run().each(function(result){
      var item={};
      item.itemID=result.getValue({name:'itemid'});
      item.internalID=result.getValue({name:'internalid'});
      itemArray.push(item);
      return true;
    });
    return itemArray;
  }

  function deleteSearch(){
    search.delete({id:'customsearch_inventory_item_search'});
  }

  buildItemArray();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do that but the idea of collecting the item ids from the line items is the one I normally use.

You can then use GetList to retrieve details about each item.

Comment: Do you have an example of some of the other ways? I will probably just end up storing the id's off in the local database but I am curious about the other methods you mentioned.

Comment: When you wrote about line items I assumed you had a  transaction record. For instance a Sales Order has a SalesOrderItemList containing SalesOrderItems. You can step through those and extract the item refs.This gives you a list of specific items. You can use the GetList method to retrieve all the details of those items in one call.  How would storing the ids help you? Maybe I didn't understand your use case.

Comment: I am trying to create a new SalesOrder. I need the internal ID's to add inventory items to the SalesOrder line items, so that it can be inserted. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If the order is coming from another source you'll need to look up the ids somehow by generating a mapping between systems. You can keep an external database of the mapping but you'll need to keep it updated which is yet another integration. I tend to try to do everything like this with Suitelets and Restlets. Way less effort.

Comment: @bknights could you help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343560/how-to-get-netsuite-bin-number-details-from-inventory-details-tab-using-soap-api